# get title and likeCount youtube API

Tags: php, youtube-api

I used the following code to get title and like count of youtube video:

```
$gdata_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$videoId.'?v=2&alt=jsonc';
$json_content = file_get_contents($gdata_url, 0, null, null);
```

But currently **title** of json response always contains **https://youtube.com/devicesupport** instead of actual title and json response does not contain **viewCount**.

Could you please advise how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Youtube API v2 has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference). You can find how to get video info with v3 [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

You use the `part` parameter to define what properties you want to retrieve. `Snippet` gives you most of the properties including title and `statistics` returns the like count. You can use `"snippet,statistics"` to get both with one call.